# Manipulate NTFS symlinks that may be in use

Tags: python, windows, symlink, ntfs

Once upon a time long long ago I had an epiphany. In the course of my job I create several more or less temporary files per day. Some of them would be useful to store for longer, some not. Because of the amount of these files, I thought that organizing them into folders per day would be a nice thing. So I created a scheduled task that would run a script every night that would create a new folder for each workday and remove old ones if they were empty.

That was fine for some time, but then I started wondering that it'd be mighty convenient if I could access **todays** folder via some shortcut, like *C:\today* or something like that. And down the rabbit hole we go...

So I modified my script to create a NTFS symlink (yes, such a thing exists!) from `C:\today` to, for example, `C:\Users\<me>\Documents\dayfolders\2017-12-01\`

Now, when I leave work, I don't meticulously close every file in every program that I happened to use (so that next morning I can pick up where I left off). This interferes with my fancy symlinking, because I cannot delete the symlink when something still uses it. So, I thought, I'd **rename** the symlink to a temporary thing in the temp dir and create a NEW one with the old name instead.
This strategy only works for the first time (or two). Up till now I've just lived with it, however I still feel that there **MAY** be a way out!

If anybody can help me, please do! :)

So, the code of my scheduled task (Python 3) :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   # some setup tasks here for logging, loading conf etc

   basepath = getbasepath(conf)
   cleanupolddirs(basepath)

   newdir = createnewdir(basepath)
   relink(conf, newdir)

   # post-run cleanup tasks here
```

and from top down, the rest of the relevant functions:

```
def getbasepath(config):
    basepath_ = config['General']['BasePath']
    if (len(basepath_) == 0) or (not os.path.exists(basepath_)):
        basepathmsg = "Error with base path. Provided path was: %s" % str(basepath_)
        logging.fatal(basepathmsg)
        logging.shutdown()
        sys.exit(basepathmsg)
    return basepath_
```

deleting empty dirs:

```
def cleanupolddirs(base):
    for d in os.listdir(base):
        try:
            wd = os.path.join(base, d)
            mode = os.stat(wd).st_mode
            if stat.S_ISDIR(mode) and not stat.S_ISLNK(mode):
                subs = os.listdir(wd)
                if len(subs) == 0:
                    logging.debug('empty dir')
                    os.rmdir(wd)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("FNFE:" + str(e))
```

now we get to the actual business. First, make a target directory for the links to point to:

```
def createnewdir(base):
    freshdir = os.path.join(base, str(date.today()))
    if not os.path.exists(freshdir):
        try:
            os.mkdir(freshdir)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("New daydir error:" + str(freshdir) + "; " + str(e))

    return freshdir
```

and now the troublesome part - renaming the current link to something in temp and creating a new one:

```
def relink(config, target):
    links = config.items('LinkPaths')
    tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    # create a link to new daydir
    for linkname, linkpath in links:
        if os.path.exists(linkpath):
            temppath = os.path.join(tempdir, os.path.basename(linkname) + str(date.today()))
            logging.info('temp path for {link} is {path}'.format(link=linkpath, path=temppath))
            try:
                os.rename(linkpath, temppath)
            except OSError as e:
                logging.error('Error renaming link ({link}): {err}'.format(link=linkpath, err=e))
            try:
                os.unlink(temppath)
            except OSError as e:
                logging.error('Error deleting temp link ({link}): {err}'.format(link=temppath, err=e))

        try:
            os.symlink(target, linkpath)
        except OSError as err:
            logging.error("Error creating/updating link ({link}): {err}".format(link=linkpath, err=err))

    try:
        shutil.rmtree(tempdir)
    except Exception as err:
        logging.error("Error removing temporary directory ({dir}): {err}".format(dir=tempdir, err=err))
```

and the logfile from the attempts illustrating the results. I start from a "clean" state where the symlinks do not exist. As can be seen from the log messages I actually attempt to keep TWO links - one directly under C:\ and the other in my profile directory.

```
2017-12-01 01:00:01,528 - INFO - temp path for C:\today is C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpltsvanzn\path12017-12-01
2017-12-01 01:00:01,573 - INFO - temp path for C:\Users\<me>\Documents\dayfolders\today is C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpltsvanzn\path22017-12-01
2017-12-02 01:00:01,460 - INFO - temp path for C:\today is C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpom8kry8p\path12017-12-02
2017-12-02 01:00:01,485 - INFO - temp path for C:\Users\<me>\Documents\dayfolders\today is C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpom8kry8p\path22017-12-02
2017-12-03 01:00:01,454 - ERROR - FNFE:[WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\<me>\\Documents\\dayfolders\\today'
2017-12-03 01:00:01,484 - ERROR - Error creating/updating link (C:\today): [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\<me>\\Documents\\dayfolders\\2017-12-03' -> 'C:\\today'
2017-12-03 01:00:01,484 - ERROR - Error creating/updating link (C:\Users\<me>\Documents\dayfolders\today): [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\<me>\\Documents\\dayfolders\\2017-12-03' -> 'C:\\Users\\<me>\\Documents\\dayfolders\\today'
```

And for every subsequent day the same errors are logged as on the 3rd of Dec.

The task is run as my user and the "Run with highest privileges" checkbox is checked. The task is also set to "Run whether user is logged on or not".

I feel that there is something very basic interfering with my plans for conquering the world, but for the life of me, I cannot see the wood for the trees.

Comment: I think it's a good question and a known problem, you would probably get more attention, when you break down your problem to the simple fact about creating a symlink and then managing to move it and recreate. +1 anyhow\

Comment: I'm a storyteller. Expressing myself shortly and concisely is **very** difficult for me :)

Comment: you not need delete, recreate, rename symlink file. you need create/open it with `OPEN_ALWAYS` Disposition and any access and then use `FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT` for set/change symlink target

Comment: At first glance - what is your symlink, `C:\today` or `C:\Users\<me>\Documents\dayfolders\today` because, judging by your log, your script is attempting both.

Comment: and of course, forget say at begin, file need create with `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` option

Comment: I initially attempted to do `C:\today` and then when I encountered the first setbacks, also tried with the latter one in Documents (in case I tripped up Windows' file system protection or something). And since then, I've left in both. But the more convenient one to have would be the first, of course.

Comment: @Manjabes - are you can use winapi and c++ structures ?

Comment: At first look, it doesn't seem that Python standard APIs provide such features. Theoretically I could use the Winapi directly with pywin32, but I'm not sure if I want to.

Comment: Please include a log every file operation (i.e. `stat`, `listdir`, `mkdir`, `symlink`, `rmdir`, `rename`, `unlink`, `rmtree`), including the arguments and the function from which it's called -- not just the failures. This will provide a complete trace of what's happening that leads to the failure.